# Deleting a record when the total number of records is 50000

Tags: apex, trigger, process-builder, visual-workflow

I want to delete the last "oldest" record from an sObject, when the total number of records is 50000.

I tried to do this with process builder, which calls a flow. But it seems that flow can’t handle so much data.

Any better Idea, how to achieve that except in trigger?

Comment: Do you need this to happen in real time, or would a regularly scheduled function suffice?

Comment: it doesn't matter, i need to have a better way to do that, instead of doing that in trigger.

Answer (score 1):

With a SOQL query, you can sort on a specific field using [ORDER BY](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_orderby.htm).

This helps you out, because the oldest record will also have the oldest timestamp in `CreatedDate`

Timestamps, I believe, are monotonically increasing (they only ever increase). So when you write your query, you'll want to sort in the ascending direction (ASC). This means the first record returned is the one that will have the smallest value in the field(s) you're ordering by (and each subsequent record will have a larger value than the last).

Things get a little more complicated if you created a whole bunch of records at the same time (like through a trigger, or through data loader). Ordering by an autonumber field (if you have one) is probably the most reliable way to do things in this (and pretty much every other) situation.

I've run into a situation myself where I needed to retrieve records in a query based on the order that they were inserted in (and they were all inserted in the same transaction). In such a situation, you'll likely need some additional field to sort by to guarantee that you get your oldest record. Ordering by `CreatedDate` alone *may* be sufficient though.

Some example code to demonstrate...

```
Contact testC1 = new Contact(
    firstName = 'test1',
    lastName = 'McPerson'
);

Contact testC2 = testC1.clone();
testC2.firstName = 'test2';

Contact testC3 = testC1.clone();
testC3.firstName = 'test3';

Contact testC4 = testC1.clone();
testC4.firstName = 'test4';

List<Contact> testContacts = new List<Contact>{testC1, testC2, testC3, testC4};
insert testContacts;

List<Contact> results = [SELECT Id, Name, CreatedDate FROM Contact WHERE CreatedDate >= :datetime.now().addSeconds(-1) ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC];
system.debug(results);

for(Contact c :results){
    system.debug(c.Name + ': ' + c.CreatedDate.getTime());
}
delete testContacts;
```

And the results:

> 08:10:18:189 USER_DEBUG [90]|DEBUG|(Contact:{Id=003n000000Ru8t1AAB, Name=test1 McPerson, CreatedDate=2018-09-17 13:10:18}, Contact:{Id=003n000000Ru8t2AAB, Name=test2 McPerson, CreatedDate=2018-09-17 13:10:18}, Contact:{Id=003n000000Ru8t3AAB, Name=test3 McPerson, CreatedDate=2018-09-17 13:10:18}, Contact:{Id=003n000000Ru8t4AAB, Name=test4 McPerson, CreatedDate=2018-09-17 13:10:18})
>
> 08:10:18:189 USER_DEBUG [93]|DEBUG|test1 McPerson: 1537189818000
>   08:10:18:189 USER_DEBUG [93]|DEBUG|test2 McPerson: 1537189818000
>   08:10:18:190 USER_DEBUG [93]|DEBUG|test3 McPerson: 1537189818000
>   08:10:18:190 USER_DEBUG [93]|DEBUG|test4 McPerson: 1537189818000

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I already did this in trigger using the creadeddate field:

Integer numOfApexLogs = [SELECT COUNT() FROM ApexLog__c];
        if (numOfApexLogs + newRecords.size() > 50000) {
            delete [SELECT Id FROM ApexLog__c ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC LIMIT :newRecords.size()];
        }


But i was wondering if there is a better way to do this than in a trigger.

Comment: @MoHamada Triggers aren't the only place where you can use SOQL. You could, for example, use this in a batch class and schedule it, make this into an `@invocableMethod` annotated method to execute it from process builder, make it `@auraEnabled` to call it from a lightning component as part of a lightning action, etc...

Answer (score 0):

get the count of record using

```
Integer count = [Select Count() from Account];
```

check if the count  is greater than 50000 if yes then query the account with

```
With a SOQL query, you can sort on a specific field using ORDER BY  like this
Account count = [Select Id,CreatedDate from Account ORDER BY CreatedDate limit 1];
```

Delete the Account.
it's you choice how will call whether or you will run batch